# What is the point of noreturn?

Tags: c++, c++11, attributes, noreturn

[[dcl.attr.noreturn]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.noreturn) provides the following example:

```
[[ noreturn ]] void f() {
    throw "error";
    // OK
}
```

but I do not understand what is the point of `[[noreturn]]`, because the return type of the function is already `void`.

So, what is the point of the `noreturn` attribute? How is it supposed to be used?

Comment: What is so important about this kind of funciton (that will most likely happen once in a program execution) that deserves such attention? Isn't this an easily detectable situation?

Comment: @MrLister The OP's conflating the concepts of “returning” and “return value”.  Given how they're nearly always used in tandem, I think the confusion is justified.

Comment: Good question and answers. But I Love your reference to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538291/what-is-the-point-of-noreturn

Answer (score 280, accepted):

The `[[noreturn]]` attribute is supposed to be used for functions that don't return to the caller. That doesn't mean `void` functions (which do return to the caller - they just don't return a value), but functions where the control flow will not return to the calling function after the function finishes (e.g. functions that exit the application, loop forever or throw exceptions as in your example).

This can be used by compilers to make some optimizations and generate better warnings. For example if `f` has the `[[noreturn]]` attribute, the compiler could warn you about `g()` being dead code when you write `f(); g();`. Similarly the compiler will know not to warn you about missing `return` statements after calls to `f()`.

Comment: What about a function such as [`execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) that _shouldn't_ return but _could_? Should it have the _noreturn_ attribute?

Comment: No, it shouldn't -- if there is a possibility for control flow to return to the caller, it must not have the `noreturn` attribute. `noreturn` may only be used if your function is guaranteed to do something that terminates the program before control flow can return to the caller -- for example because you call exit(), abort(), assert(0), etc.

Comment: Does that include returning via exception throw (so to speak), or do thrown exceptions skip `catch`es outside of the `noreturn` function, or is throwing exceptions from within the `noreturn` function disallowed?

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson If a call to a noreturn function is wrapped in a try-block, any code from the catch block on will count as reachable again.

Comment: @sepp2k Cool.  So it's not impossible to return, just abnormal.  That's useful.  Cheers.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson no, it's impossible to return. Throwing an exception is not returning, so if every path throws then it's `noreturn`. Handling that exception is not the same as it having returned. Any code within the `try` after the call is still unreachable, and if not `void` then any assignment or use of the return value will not happen.

Comment: @JonHanna Yes obviously it's impossible to formally `return`; however I was asking if it was possible to do a general return-type-execution-operation. That's why I said _“returning via exception throw (so to speak)”_. I should've probably have written _“accomplishing (hacky) functionality akin to return using `throw`”_ or just _“exiting the function execution and continuing in the enclosing call using `throw`”_. Everybody here knows that `throw` doesn't have return values, and that it resumes execution at the `catch`. I was asking for return-like capability, not `return`.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson I wouldn't be so sure that "*everyone knows*" -- keep in mind that people _extremely_ new to C++ and programming in general are on this site, too, and it'd be far too easy for them to read your comments and assume that `throw`ing was a type of `return`ing. I'm aware that wasn't your intention, but that's why it's worth explicitly pointing out, even though everyone _who commented_ likely knew the difference. (Also, sorry for necro, but no one else explained so I felt like someone should.)

Comment: @sepp2k I think it would be worth [edit]ing this answer to explicitly mention how `throw` is treated. While it's implied already, it makes it clearer and costs very little to add the sentences "`throw`ing from a `[[noreturn]]` function is possible, and works as expected -- the only think you can't do is `return`. If you wrap the call in a `try`/`catch`, you can treat it like any other throwing function." (Probably written better, though.)

Comment: @RavuAlHemio Not exactly. Since the question is marked "C++", and it even has a `throw` inside its example, there comes _exceptional control flow_. Such a function is assumed never returning, and it can also avoid to terminate at the same time. In the ISO C++ parlance, it merely "exits via an exception". (OTOH, with ISO C, there is no such choice.)

Comment: It may be also worth mentioning G++'s `-Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn` warns against functions that only throw without attributes to indicate `noreturn`. This shows (purely) throwing is one of the exact case to be served by `[[noreturn]]`.

Answer (score 74):

`noreturn` doesn't tell the compiler that the function doesn't return any value.  It tells the compiler that *control flow will not return to the caller*.  This allows the compiler to make a variety of optimizations -- it need not save and restore any volatile state around the call, it can dead-code eliminate any code that would otherwise follow the call, etc.

Comment: Be careful to use [[noreturn]]. Because if the function contains while loop, and you break the loop unintentionally, the program may act wired.

Comment: @CuteDoge A compiler should emit a diagnostic in this case.  It is not `[[maybe_noreturn]]`.  For example a void function returning a value gives a warning.  If you have warnings turned off or ignored a diagnostic, you have other problems.

Answer (score 34):

Previous answers correctly explained what noreturn is, but not **why** it exists. I don't think the "optimization" comments is the main purpose: Functions which do not return are rare and usually do not need to be optimized. Rather I think the main raison d'être of noreturn is to avoid false-positive warnings. For example, consider this code:

```
int f(bool b){
    if (b) {
        return 7;
    } else {
        abort();
    }
 }
```

Had abort() not been marked "noreturn", the compiler might have warned about this code having a path where f does not return an integer as expected. But because abort() is marked no return it knows the code is correct.

Comment: All the other examples listed use void functions -- how does it work when you have both the [[no return]] directive and a non-void return type? Does the [[no return]] directive only come into play when the compiler gets ready to warn about a possibility of not returning and ignore the warning? For example, does the compiler go:

"Okay, here is a non-void function."
* continues compiling *
"Oh crap, this code might not return! Should I warn the user?*
"Nevermind, I see the no-return directive. Carry on"

Comment: The noreturn function in my example is not f(), it's abort(). It doesn't make sense to mark a non-void function noreturn. A function which sometimes returns a value and sometimes returns (a good example is execve()) cannot be marked noreturn.

Comment: implicit-fallthrough is another such example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129741/gcc-7-wimplicit-fallthrough-warnings-and-portable-way-to-clear-them/52707279#52707279

Answer (score 33):

It means that the function will not complete. The control flow will never hit the statement after the call to `f()`:

```
void g() {
   f();
   // unreachable:
   std::cout << "No! That's impossible" << std::endl;
}
```

The information can be used by the compiler/optimizer in different ways. The compiler can add a warning that the code above is unreachable, and it can modify the actual code of `g()` in different ways for example to support continuations.

Comment: gcc/clang [don't give warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5563e13b0ff475ba4131e93d7c461093-eae62b55f4d064645734b0b710d33419)

Comment: @TemplateRex: Compile with `-Wno-return` and you will get a warning. Probably not the one you were expecting but it is probably sufficient to tell you that the compiler has knowledge of what `[[noreturn]]` is and it can take advantage of it. (I am a bit surprised that `-Wunreachable-code` did not kick in...)

Comment: @TemplateRex: Sorry `-Wmissing-noreturn`, the warning implies that flow analysis determined that the `std::cout` is not reachable. I don't have a new enough gcc at hand to look at the generated assembly, but I would not be surprised if the call to `operator<<` was dropped

Comment: now it works, and it's a pretty decent one (essentially: `[[noreturn]]` should be applied transitively towards the outer-most scope)

Comment: Here's an [assembly dump](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c9cacd3fbd9fd577536cd1475bfe013b-9c7308574711704234cea5c23ddac68e) (-S -o - flags in coliru), indeed drops the "unreachable" code. Interestingly enough, [`-O1` is already enough](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b20ef43ae16e5b1901ab38eb795c81e3-fb3032ec106960b49620c826fab4a73a) to drop that unreachable code without the `[[noreturn]]` hint.

Comment: @TemplateRex: All of the code is in the same translation unit and visible, so the compiler can infer the `[[noreturn]]` from the code. If this translation unit only had a declaration of the function that was defined somewhere else, the compiler would not be able to drop that code, as it does not *know* that the function does not return. That is where the attribute should help the compiler.

Answer (score 16):

Type theoretically speaking, `void` is what is called in other languages `unit` or `top`. Its logical equivalent is *True*. Any value can be legitimately cast to `void` (every type is a subtype of `void`). Think about it as "universe" set; there are no operations in common to *all* the values in the world, so there are no valid operations on a value of type `void`. Put it another way, telling you that something belongs to the universe set gives you no information whatsoever - you know it already. So the following is sound:

```
(void)5;
(void)foo(17); // whatever foo(17) does
```

But the assignment below is not:

```
void raise();
void f(int y) {
    int x = y!=0 ? 100/y : raise(); // raise() returns void, so what should x be?
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

`[[noreturn]]`, on the other hand, is called sometimes `empty`, `Nothing`, `Bottom` or `Bot` and is the logical equivalent of *False*. It has no values at all, and an expression of this type can be cast to (i.e is subtype of) any type. This is the empty set. Note that if someone tells you "the value of the expression foo() belongs to the empty set" it is *highly* informative - it tells you that this expression will never complete its normal execution; it will abort, throw or hang. It is the exact opposite of `void`.

So the following does not make sense (pseudo-C++, since `noreturn` is not a first-class C++ type)

```
void foo();
(noreturn)5; // obviously a lie; the expression 5 does "return"
(noreturn)foo(); // foo() returns void, and therefore returns
```

But the assignment below is perfectly legitimate, since `throw` is understood by the compiler to not return:

```
void f(int y) {
    int x = y!=0 ? 100/y : throw exception();
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

In a perfect world, you could use `noreturn` as the return value for the function `raise()` above:

```
noreturn raise() { throw exception(); }
...
int x = y!=0 ? 100/y : raise();
```

Sadly C++ does not allow it, probably for practical reasons. Instead it gives you the ability to use `[[ noreturn ]]` attribute which helps guiding compiler optimizations and warnings.

Comment: Nothing may be cast to `void` and `void` never evaluates to `true` or `false` or anything else.

Comment: Everything may be cast to `void`. and `void` never evaluates to `true` since `bool` is subtype of `void` and not the other way around.
Again, everything said here is type-theoretical. nothing C++-centric. `void` is not a 1st-class citizen in the C++ type system.

Comment: When I say `true`, I don't mean "the value `true` of the type `bool`" but the logic sense, see [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)

Comment: Abstract type theory which does not fit the type system of a specific language is irrelevant when discussing the type system of that language. The question, in question :-), is about C++, not type theory.

Comment: Specifically to this question, abstract type-theory gives the perfect answer. C++ does not brutally violates it (since it is pretty much consistent) in this case.

Comment: Why else can you do in C++ stuff like `y!=0 ? x/y : throw exception()`

Comment: Specifically to this answer, it suggests that `void(true)` is allowed in C++. It is not. `y != 0 ? x / y : throw exception()` has nothing to do with how `void` is treated as a type.

Comment: `(void)true;` is perfectly valid, as the answer suggests. `void(true)` is something completely different, syntactically. It is an attempt to create a new object of type `void` by calling a constructor with `true` as an argument; this fails, among other reasons, because `void` is not first class.

Comment: So it is. I'm accustomed to using type(value) casting, not c style casting.

Comment: @Clearer What language, exactly, are you used to?

Comment: @Elazar, I'm also curious as to which language you're used to. Neither of you make much sense, being unfamiliar with C-style languages which are the cornerstone of modern programming, by many people's standards.

Comment: I used C/C++ notation, just like the OP.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @JoshSanford it explains the difference between `void` and `noreturn` in type-theoretic term, complementing the (admittedly more useful) practical answers above.

Comment: @Elazar: `void(foo())` is fine—but if it’s an entire statement then it’s a function declaration.

Comment: Some claims are technically wrong. If a function declared with `[[noreturn]]` returns, the behavior is undefined. This grants implementations the permission to assume the function never returns, without a single instance of the value ever meeting the concept "unit". It's actually a special kind of [_bottom_ type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type). The type `void` is another kind that it "raises" a translation-time exception ("compiling error") on value-returning instead. I'm a bit curious which languages name the case `unit` or `top`.

Comment: The type `void` can be a unit type only when the use of expressions of `void` type is well-formed (e.g. returning a `void` expression in a function declared `void`) and well-defined (e.g. at least without `[[noreturn]]` in the declaration of that function), which is essentially context-dependent. This means `void` is never a first-class unit type in C++. On the other hand, the type `void*` can be a valid example of the top type, when the standard conversions are fabricated in the typing rules. The type `void*` is never a unit type as it can have more than one well-defined values in a program.

Comment: Yes, `void` is not first class. But `void*` is neither a unit type nor top. `void` is a non-first-class unit type (top), and `void*` is more like a `ref top`. Structs cannot be meaningfully casted to `void*`, but can be casted to `void` wherever the type system does not decide to (arbitrarily) discriminate that type.

Comment: I return void, therefore I am.

Comment: As for now, this is probably the only more-or-less valid answer to the question here. It's a pity, that C++ (even as of c++17) can't yet do `int x = y!=0 ? 100/y : raise()` (for many years, I was sure it can; and I have stumbled upon that only now). That greatly reduces the usefulness of `[[noreturn]]` in C++.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my viewpoint about `[[noreturn]]` in the very simple and short terminology.

1. It was introduced in C++11.
2. A function using `[[noreturn]]` attributes returns nothing at all; it is different from `void funcs()`, which returns nothing.
3. To clarify, you cannot use the *[[noreturn]]* attribute with void functions.
4. It was mainly introduced for performance reasons. When a function is marked with the *[[noreturn]]* attribute, the compiler knows it does not have to return to the caller; it does not generate any code; hence there are small performance benefits.
5. The prominent use cases are:

   - For throwing errors/exceptions:

     ```cpp
     #include <iostream>

     [[noreturn]] void foo() {
         throw std::logic_error("error");
     }

     void bar() {
         try {
             foo();
             std::cout << "Hello";  // will never return here, therefore can never be printed
         } catch (std::logic_error &e) {
             std::cout << "World";
         }
     }

     int main() {
         bar();
         return 0;
     }
     ```
   - To exit code:

     ```cpp
     #include <iostream>
     #include <cstdlib>

     [[noreturn]] void foo() {
         std::cerr << "Error";
         std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     int main() {
         foo();  // when called prints Error and exit code.
         return 0;
     }
     ```
6. If the functions actually return something and you have defined *[[noreturn]]* to it, it'll produce undefined behavior to warn the user. Example:

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>

   [[noreturn]] int foo() {  // defined [[noreturn]]
       return 411;  // returns integer (411)
   }

   int main() {
       int k = foo();
       std::cout << k;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Compiler output (GCC): (as mentioned above, shows undefined behavior)

   ```cpp
   <source>: In function 'int foo()':
   <source>:4:12: warning: function declared 'noreturn' has a 'return' 
   statement
       4 |     return 411;
         |            ^~~
   <source>:4:12: warning: 'noreturn' function does return
       4 |     return 411;
         |            ^
   ASM generation compiler returned: 0
   <source>: In function 'int foo()':
   <source>:4:12: warning: function declared 'noreturn' has a 'return' statement
      4 |     return 411;
        |            ^~~
   <source>:4:12: warning: 'noreturn' function does return
      4 |     return 411;
        |            ^
   Execution build compiler returned: 0
   Program returned: 139
   Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV
   ```

I hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: "To clarify, you cannot use the [[noreturn]] attribute with void functions." Yes, you can, and your first example does exactly that.