# Clang warning in dubious case: function 'foo' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn'?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, warnings, noreturn

I have been playing around a bit with the [[noreturn]] attribute, which I'm trying to get a handle of and make use of (I understand `[[noreturn]]` is a [C++11 standard attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) and `__attribute__((noreturn))` is a GCC/Clang extension). As part of this, I enabled the Clang warning -Wmissing-noreturn.

```
> clang++ -v
Ubuntu clang version 3.7.1-svn253742-1~exp1 (branches/release_37) (based on LLVM 3.7.1)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

foo.cpp:

```
enum bar
{
  A = 1,
  B,
  C
};

void foo()
{
  switch (bar())
  {
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
    default:
      break;
  }
}

int main()
{
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Then compile:

```
> clang++ foo.cpp -o foo -Wmissing-noreturn -std=c++14
foo.cpp:9:1: warning: function 'foo' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn'
      [-Wmissing-noreturn]
{
^
1 warning generated.
```

**It appears to me that it would return! What's going on here?** Is this a compiler bug?

If you remove the "= 1" from A, then it compiles fine without a warning.

If I do make the foo() function `[[noreturn]] void foo()`, then it does crash with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Looks like a clang bug to me.

Comment: I can reproduce with Apple (XCode) `clang++` (version info `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)`
`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0`
`Thread model: posix`).  I'm not sure I can interpret it yet — what does the default constructor for an `enum` return?  (Dinking with your code, it appears that `bar()` returns 0 — which is interesting.  But doesn't mean that the function doesn't return.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - good question. If I make it "A = 0", it doesn't have the warning. I was playing around with an enum class before, which behaves the same. Perhaps it always initialises it to 0 by default, which is invalid, and becomes a trap rather than dropping to default? Or undefined behaviour?

Comment: Superficially, the `default:` clause should catch the value 0 too, if the return from the enumeration constructor generating a value that isn't in the range of the enumeration isn't a problem. Given that `A = 0` in the enumeration alters things, it's going to take analysis of the wording, but at best the error message is misleading, I think. I'd support @VaughnCato's analysis provisionally: a bug in `clang++`. —— FYI: C11 has `_Noreturn` as a keyword and `<stdnoreturn.h>` to provide a macro `#define noreturn _Noreturn`.  But it's not enclosed in `[[noreturn]]` in C11. That's wholly tangential.

Answer (score -1):

Ok sorry for delete the last answer. It was wrong. Ok noreturn meann that the function never end. and the segementation fould is because bar is not a variable

Comment: The attribute `noreturn` (however it is decorated) means that when this function is called, the flow of control will never return from the function.  That typically means that it, in turn, calls a function such as `exit()` or `_exit()` or something similar that stops the program.  In the sample code, the only function called from within `foo()` is `bar()` — and that is a default constructor for the `enum bar { … };` type.  It is not immediately obvious why that would not return — and if it does, then the function `foo()` would return, so the `noreturn` attribute would be inappropriate.

Answer (score -3):

Just to give a follow up to an old question: `clang` is correct, even if a little pedantic.

Indeed the attribute `noreturn` is applicable to your `foo()` function, since it doesn't return anything. The fact that `clang` of 2016 gets confused with the slight variation in the enumeration that is a problem.

But we should forgive `clang` for this *pecadillo*, for C++11 grammar is not what could be called very simple.

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain how foo() does not return to the caller! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538291/what-is-the-point-of-noreturn

Comment: Additionally, how is Clang correct if doing the suggested [[noreturn]] causes it to crash with a segfault??