# Are noreturn attributes on exiting functions necessary?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

Are `noreturn` attributes on never-returning functions necessary, or is this just an (arguably premature? -- at least for exits, I can't imagine why optimize there) optimization?

It was explained to me that in a context such as

```
void myexit(int s) _Noreturn {
   exit(s);
}
// ...
if (!p) { myexit(1); } 
f(*p);
/// ...
```

`noreturn` prevents the `!p` branch from being optimized out.
But is it really permissible for a compiler to optimize out that branch?
I realize the rationale for optimizing it out would be: "Undefined behavior can't happen. If `p` == `NULL`, dereferencing it is UB,  therefore `p` can never be `NULL` in this context, therefore the `!p` branch does  not trigger". But can't the compiler resolve the problem just as well by assuming that `myexit` could be a function that doesn't return (even if it's not explicitly marked as such)?

Comment: I'm hesitant to mark this C++ too because of downvote happy purists, but C++ has noreturn attributes (`[[noreturn]]`) too, and a C/C++ answer would be most welcome.

Comment: _"noreturn prevents the `!p` branch from being optimized out."_ why?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538291/what-is-the-point-of-noreturn

Comment: @mvidelgauz That cannot be a dup, because of the tags. Please be attentive.

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate of the linked question.  I'm not asking what noreturn attributes are good for or whether they are nice. I'm asking whether it's **necessary** to apply them to functions that exit. The  rationale for possibly optimizing out the `!p` branch is in the question and whether or not that's a good rationale is part of  the question.

Comment: Ok, I have read that  rationale but I still can't get it, sorry (i.e. what exactly makes compiler **sure** that "p can never be NULL", to me this code looks like run-time check for this condition)

Comment: _"I'm asking whether it's necessary to apply.."_ In other words, you are asking about possible situations when _not applying_ it can lead to bad results?

Comment: @mvidelgauz The rumor has it that compilers are **allowed to assume** undefined behavior never occurs and that some compilers would use that assumption to deduce possibly ill-advised optimization opportunities. There's a whole bunch of blog posts and videos on this and how it can cause problems on modern, "very smart, very optimizing" compilers.

Comment: @mvidelgauz That is correct.

Comment: But with such "optimization" compiler will remove !p branch regardless of whether there is `noreturn` or not. Am I wrong? Are you saying that  `noretun` will give compiler an additional hint saying _"in case p is NULL f(*p) code won't be reached so this is useful code that should NOT be removed so that exit will happen instead of UB"_?

Comment: The assertion that p is not NULL is actually only valid below the if, so the compiler cannot remove the if statement.

Comment: @martinkunev: No, UB is allowed to go back in time and change previous results. 'Undefined' really has no limit here, not even nasal demons.

Comment: @sp2danny UB is not some fairy that changes your code. If what you're saying were true, how could you verify that a variable is not NULL? Dereferencing a NULL pointer is UB so the compiler will just ignore that possibility and optimize, asserting that when a pointer is dereferenced, it is not NULL. For good explanation of UB, I would suggest this: blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @martinkunev The compiler can assume that UB never occurs and therefore rearrange code in a way that would make it seem like the UB went back in time, were it to occur. See this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) for an example.

Comment: @a3f This is not the case here. The contract is the compiler produces a program with the SAME behavior as the code, if the code does not lead to UB. In the example, the code does not lead to UB (NULL pointer will never be dereferenced). The compiler can rearrange the code but it can NOT change the behavior of a conforming program. It has only the right to assume that when `f` is called, `p` is not NULL. The compiler cannot prove that the `if` statement doesn't change `p` and that `f` is always called when the `if` is reached (because this is false). So the two lines cannot be rearranged.

Comment: @martinkunev Whether this is or isn't the case here is the point of OP's question. Refer to my answer for my assessment. Feel free to add your answer too. I was just addressing your "UB is not some fairy that changes your code." comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This allows for several optimizations to take place. First, for the call itself this may to allow for a simplified setup, not all registers have to be saved, a `jmp` instruction can be used instead of `call` or similar. Then the code after the call can also be optimized because there is no branching back to the normal flow.

So yes, usually `_Noreturn` is a valuable information to the compiler.

But as a direct answer to your question, no, this is a property for optimization, so it is not *necessary*.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the question, though.

Comment: @JensGustedt It's not very detailed but at least it answer the main part off the question now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Axiom:** The standard is the definite resource on what's well-defined in C.

- The standard specifies `assert`, therefore using `assert` is well-defined.
- `assert` conditionally calls `abort`, a `_Noreturn` function, therefore that's allowed.
- Every usage of `assert` is inside a function. Therefore functions may or may not return.
- The standard has this example:

  ```
  _Noreturn void g (int i) { // causes undefined behavior if i <= 0
      if (i > 0) abort();
  }
  ```

  Therefore functions conditionally returning must not be `_Noreturn`.
  This means:

  - For externally defined functions, the compiler has to assume the function might not return and isn't free to optimize out the `if`-branch
  - For "internally" defined functions, the compiler can check whether the function indeed always returns and optimize out the branch.

In both cases, compiled program behavior aligns with what a non-optimizing abstract C machine would do and the 'as-if' rule is observed.

Comment: Thought writing it out as kind of proof would be cool, now looking at it, I am not so sure anymore. But it answers the question I think. :-) Feel free to edit it to make it more formal.

Comment: A compiler can't assume that externally-defined functions' don't return; instead it must be prepared to handle both the cases in which the function does return (code which follows the function cannot be omitted) and also the cases where it doesn't (code which follows the function cannot affect the execution of the function or anything before it).

Comment: @supercat, reworded it. Thanks.