# How to use [[noreturn]] attribute in c++?

Tags: c++, attributes

According to [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538291/what-is-the-point-of-noreturn), The `[[noreturn]]` attribute specifies that a function does not return. Ok, thats fine.

But I don't understand how to use `[[noreturn]]` attribute in program. I tried to use `[[noreturn]]` attribute in my code. But when I compiled my code in GCC compiler, I got following error.

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
 [[noreturn]] void f(int i) {
 ^
cp1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cp1.cpp:11:6: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
  f(10);
```

My code is here:

```
#include <cstdlib>

[[noreturn]] void f(int i) {
  if (i > 0)
    throw "Received positive input";
  std::exit(0);
}

int main()
{
        f(10);
}
```

How to use `[[noreturn]]` attribute in C++?

Comment: Your code should work as-is: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a24777527dc295d3. Are you sure that you have set C++14 compiler switch?

Comment: Wrong compiler. Here is GCC example:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5f96e643a3672b0

Answer (score 4):

You are definitely using a non-compliant C++11 compiler or a pre-C++11 compiler, or your flags isn't set to `-std=c++11`? (at least).

If you are stuck with pre-C++11 compilers, you can wrap up a simple macro that uses built-in compiler attributes in a hopefully portable way:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define NO_RETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
#elif __MINGW32__
#define NO_RETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
#elif __clang__
#define NO_RETURN __attribute__((noreturn))
#elif _MSC_VER
#define NO_RETURN __declspec(noreturn)
#endif
```

And then use as:

```
NO_RETURN void f(int i) {
  if (i > 0)
    throw "Received positive input";
  std::exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the attribute was not supported by the compiler then, It was passed now, Here are my gcc version:
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.