# Return exception from function (not throw in function) for message formatting?

Tags: c++, exception, return-type

I have a function that performs basic string formatting to generate an error description string as input to `std::runtime_error`:

```
std::string errormsg(int i)
{
  std::string str;
  // .. do something with str
  return str;
}
```

... such that:

```
void some_process(int x)
{
  if (x < 0)
    throw std::runtime_error(errmsg(x));
}
```

My intuition is that this could be simplified by using a function that directly returns an exception type; using a more complete example:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
std::runtime_error error(const char * frmt, Ts ... args)
{
    const int n = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, frmt, args...);
    std::vector<char> buff(n + 1);
    std::snprintf(&buff[0], n + 1, frmt, args...);
    return std::runtime_error(std::string(buff.data()));
}
```

... which simplifies to `throw error("Error code %d", x)`.

But I found it difficult to find code examples where exception types are returned from a wrapper function. Hence, would the above be considered bad practice, or otherwise unsafe?

Comment: Just take it to the next level: You could write a function that formats the string, creates an exception and throws it.

Comment: you could inherit from `std::runtime_error` then calling the function becomes a call to a constructor. Nothing unusual about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about exception types. They are types like others, just that they are meant to be thrown as exception. Consider that you can `throw` objects of any type not just types inheriting from `std::exception`.

The reason you did not find examples is perhaps that it is more typical to inherit from `std::runtime_error` and then just call the constructor when you want to throw it. Something along the line of

```
struct my_runtime_error : std::runtime_error {
{
    template<typename ... Ts>
    my_runtime_error(const char * frmt, Ts ... args);
};
```

Or as suggested in a comment, write a function that returns `void` and instead `throw`s the exception itself:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
[[ noreturn ]] void throw_error(const char * frmt, Ts ... args)
{
    const int n = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, frmt, args...);
    std::vector<char> buff(n + 1);
    std::snprintf(&buff[0], n + 1, frmt, args...);
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string(buff.data()));
}
```

to be used as

```
void some_process(int x)
{
   if (x < 0)
      throw_error(errmsg(x));
}
```

However, this has the disadvantage of always throwing from the same function instead of the place where actually the problem occurs and if I had to choose between this and yours I would go for your solution.

PS: note that `std::exception` and its descendants are meant to be inherited from in contrast to most other types in the standard library. `std::exception` does have a virtual destructor.

Comment: You should probably mark the `throw_error` function as `[[noreturn]]` as well.

Comment: @walnut I dont like to use stuff I dont know what it is good for, and I have to admit, I dont know hat `[[noreturn]]` really does. Can you give me a link? cppref does not mention why I would use it

Comment: @YSC thought the same, but missed to mention it, I'll add a note

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538291/what-is-the-point-of-noreturn). Basically I think the most important point is that it will allow the compiler to give better warnings, e.g. about unreachable code and missing return statements, see https://godbolt.org/z/_om3TK for an example.

Comment: Inherit from runtime_error and call yours Formatted_runtime_error. `throw Formatted_runtime_error("x may not be negative: %d", x);`

Comment: @Brandin not sure what you want to tell me. This is the first option I mention in the answer (just with a different name)