# C++: [[maybe_noreturn]]

Tags: c++

As far as I am aware, there is no `[[maybe_noreturn]]` attribute in C++.

I have a function which looks like this:

```
void func() {
    try {
        do_something();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::exit(1);
    }
}
```

If I would mark `func` as `[[noreturn]]` I'd run into UB for the happy case. Is it UB when I do not return from a function that is not marked as `[[noreturn]]`?

Or are there other language constructs, compiler extensions or libraries that implement something like `[[maybe_noreturn]]`?

Comment: `[[noreturn]]` may only be used when the function is guaranteed to not return.

Comment: What would you like `[[maybe_noreturn]]` to signify? Is this to signal something to the compiler? To the library user? How would I, as another developer, change how I interact with the function if you mark it `[[maybe_noreturn]]`?

Comment: `std::exit` is `[[noreturn]]`, it's enough.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538363/2027196

Comment: Aren't functions essentially `maybe_noreturn` by default unless you add a `noexcept` specifier?

Comment: `noexcept` functions are very much "maybe_noreturn". In fact, they are more likely to terminate than other functions since any exception escaping them will cause them to terminate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it UB when I do not return from a function that is not marked as [[noreturn]]?

No, it's well defined to terminate the program from a function regardless whether it has `[[noreturn]]` attribute or not. Using `[[noreturn]]` is optional when it is appropriate - i.e. when a function terminates unconditionally - but it is always recommended in such cases.

No such attribute as `[[maybe_noreturn]]` is needed. If it were necessary, then you would find that you would have to declare any function potentially calling `[[maybe_noreturn]]` function to also be `[[maybe_noreturn]]`, and then functions that call those functions, all the way to the top of the call chain.